# When should I raise PermissionDenied and when return HttpResponseForbidden in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling to understand the different use cases for `django.http.HttpResponseForbidden` and `rest_framework.exceptions.PermissionDenied`.

When should I rather raise the exception than returning a response? Why the exception anyway, if it is later handled as a 403 response?

Comment: Because often the handler will produce a more pleasant page than just "permission denied".

Comment: Another thing I found is that the exception will yield problems with queries not executed within an `transaction.atomic`, which would be another reason for the response.

Comment: well that is more poor view management. Especially since all sorts of ORM calls can fail, for example due to constraints at the database (like a `UNIQUE` check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When should I rather raise the exception than returning a response?

You can always raise a `PermissionDenied`. It will then be handled by the handler, which will often render a template to produce an exception that looks more visually pleasant.

In some cases you might want to render a custom template for a specific forbidden response, for example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.template import loader

def some_view(request):
    if some_condition:
        response = loader.render_to_string(
            'some_forbidden_template.html',
            context,
            request
        )
        return HttpResponseForbidden(response)
    # …
```

> Why the exception anyway, if it is later handled as a 403 response?

Not all functions can return a `HttpResponseForbidden` (or a `HttpResponse` in general). For example the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) of a `ListView` should always return a `QuerySet`. It can however throw a `PermissionDenied` exception, which will then be watched by the middleware and thus invoke the 403 handler.

An exception is thus more "reusable" in all sorts of helper functions, whereas only views, and helper functions to generate responses are supposed to return a `HttpResponse`.